# platform neutral call for new plot

Tags: r

I have a function that calls multiple windows (new graphics device window).  To make this happen I use windows().  This works but as this is for a package how do I make it platform neutral so each plot gets plotted in a new window while leaving the old window?

**What I currently have:**

```
WORD.C <- function(WORDS){
require(wordcloud)

L2 <- lapply(WORDS, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

    FUN <- function(X){
        windows()  #how to make this platform neutral
        wordcloud(X[, 1], X[, 2], min.freq=1)
    }
    lapply(L2, FUN)
}

WORD.C(list.xy)
```

Comment: `window` and `x11` are generic in the sense that those are mapped properly and will work on any OS flavour. This will not play nice with `Sweave` if you care about that.

Comment: @Dr G could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: should you perhaps add a `if (dev.interactive()) dev.new()` so that the function still produces something useful on non-interactive devices like `pdf`? I like how `grid` graphics allow you to disentangle the plot creation from its drawing on the device, it makes it trivial to define, say, a `print()` method for each plot that calls either `dev.new()` or `grid.newpage()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will `dev.new()`  cover your needs?  It opens a graphics window of the default type set up in your console sessions.

Comment: This appears to be the easiest solution.  Thank you.  The X11 worked as will but throws up warnings where as the dev. new does not appear to.

Answer (score 4):

The Mac will generally open up an X11 window, so this might be a minimal solution:

```
if( .Platform$OS.type =="unix" ) { X11() } else { windows() }
```

If you want to branch on the GUI type then you could use:

```
if( .Platform$GUI %in% ("X11", "Tk") ) { X11() } else { 
      if ( .Platform$GUI == "AQUA" ){ quartz()} else {
             windows()                            }     }
# For more details
?.Platform
?Devices
```

Comment: AFAIK X11()/x11() works everywhere, you do not need to check for platform.

Comment: @DWin your approach works as does X11 [with warnings] but I think the dev.new() is more generic.  Thank you.

Comment: @DWin thanks for sharing the .Platform$GUI as well.  I didn't know about that.  Pretty nifty